# Alternative to LastPass

Tags: android, web-apps, chrome, password-manager

Today LastPass announced that they had been acquired by LogMeIn. I'm not a fan of LogMeIn, and as I rely heavily on LastPass, I feel I should have an alternative ready.

So my requirements are:

- Function on Chrome (as a plugin)
- Android app
- Web app
- Does not require a Windows program (i.e.: Keepass has a Windows program, and the browser plugins communicate with this program)
- Storage is online (files in AppData are ok, but not a file which I need to set where it is stored)

I am a premium LastPass user, so I am prepared to pay.

Edit: I only have two main requirements - the ability to stay logged in, and auto-filling the username and password field - pretty basic features, probably available in all password managers

Comment: What are the actual password management features you need? (Not everyone knows/used LastPass, and maybe you don’t need *all* features LastPass offered.)

Comment: For Keepass, you are incorrect in stating that all browser plugins communicate with this program. I.e. the "KeepassX on rollapp" is able to communicate with Dropbox or Google Drive, making it non-dependent on the windows program

Comment: @holroy - thanks, that's interesting, but i would still have to manage the database myself - correct?

Comment: @CalvT, what do you mean with "manage it yourself"? Who else who should update it?

Comment: @holroy - I mean this: do I have to create the database, and set were it's stored? With your example of KeepassX, I would have to create a KeePass database and set it to be stored in my DropBox or GDrive account, which then anyone who has access to those accounts can then see it. Yes, I know they wouldn't have the main password, so where's the issue? I just don't like the thought, and would prefer a solution the way it worked with LastPass

Comment: You'll have to store it within your personal account at Dropbox (or Google Drive), just the same as LastPass does. The only difference is that if someone have access to your _personal_ account they can see the encrypted KeePass file, whilst you can't access the LastPass file directly.

Comment: Storing the file should be a one time operation.

Comment: The first negative (for many people) consequence of this acquisition: trusted devices expire after 30 days. https://blog.lastpass.com/2015/11/new-in-security-expiring-trusted-devices-after-30-days.html/

Comment: @CalvT, How much are you prepared to pay?

Answer (score 3):

And there's another quality app since years called [RoboForm](http://www.roboform.com).

Some [features](http://www.roboform.com/key-features):

> **Cross-Browser Support**
>
> Our password manager integrates with IE, Firefox, Chrome on Windows as well as Chrome and Safari for Macs, allowing you to share info between browsers and making your web experience faster, easier and more secure.
>
> **Complete Data Flexibility**
>
> Store, sync, and back up your RoboForm data with our RoboForm Everywhere feature. Not comfortable with the cloud yet? Then use our Desktop mode and store your information on your computer only. You get complete control and flexibility of your RoboForm data.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Padlock](http://padlock.io/). It is a Chrome extension ([available in the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/padlock/npkoefjfcjbknoeadfkbcdpbapaamcif)).

- works in Chrome
- works with Android (if Chrome is installed)
- not restricted to Windows (works on any OS with Chrome installed)
- Offline app but has sync (Padlock Cloud)

Answer (score 1):

[**Kaspersky Password Manager**](http://www.kaspersky.com/en/password-manager)

> Kaspersky Password Manager securely stores all your passwords and synchronizes them across PC, Mac, Android & iOS devices – for safer access to your favourite accounts, apps & websites.
>
> - Stores all your passwords securely
> - Synchronize passwords via multiple devices
> - Simplifies ‘sign in’ for sites and apps
> - Generates strong passwords on PC
> - Fills in online forms on your PC or Mac
> - FREE version lets you manage 15 passwords
> - Premium version - for any number of passwords
> - Simplifies synchronization & security

Answer (score 0):

One of the most popular free open-source alternatives to LastPass is [BitWarden](https://bitwarden.com/).

They do have a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bitwarden-free-password-m/nngceckbapebfimnlniiiahkandclblb?hl=en) with autofill support, and also Windows, Android and web apps.

The image below is from their Chrome extension page.

[image: BitWarden Chrome Extension]