# Recommendation(s) for a password manager

Tags: windows, android, password-manager

I've been using [Lastpass](http://lastpass.com/) for a while, primarily because of Leo Laporte and Steve Gibson's [enthusiasm](https://www.grc.com/sn/sn-256.htm) for it.  And it worked great.  And then they made it a browser on Android, and then there was a new UI that didn't work on Windows, and now it's bad enough that I have to debug it when it tries to auto add a new site.  The browser extension doesn't start up reliably (but that might be my own fault), and I'm generally pretty frustrated with the software and their support, to the point that I did not re-up my premium subscription.  While troubleshooting Lastpass, I found that they were [acquired](https://blog.lastpass.com/2015/10/lastpass-joins-logmein.html/) by [LogMeIn](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/10/logmein-buys-lastpass-password-manager-for-110-million/), and [many users](https://www.grahamcluley.com/lastpass-jump-ship/) had [disparaging](https://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=131235&sid=8618ea443024161c1c2ecfab774ec1d0) comments [and concerns](http://betanews.com/2015/10/09/lastpass-sold-to-logmein-should-linux-users-panic/) about [LogMeIn](http://venturebeat.com/2015/10/09/lastpass-users-panic-after-company-sells-to-logmein-for-110m/) and the [acquisition](http://phandroid.com/2015/10/09/logmein-buys-lastpass/).

I looked around here and saw similar dissatisfaction with LastPass.  [This question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25553/alternative-to-lastpass), while similar in nature, has a different set of requirements.

**Requirements in a password Manager:**

1. Support for Windows
2. Support for Android
3. Browser integration/support (For at least Firefox)
4. Uses a TNO (Trust No One) model for security
5. Synchronization, preferably with my own server, but cloud is OK with TNO.
6. Secure password generation, with configurable complexity options per account.
7. The ability to detect a new site automatically.
8. Graceful support of other miscellaneous extra authentications (bank PINs, 2 factor, etc), or the ability to ignore it.
9. Does not add unnecessary/unrelated features (for example, Lastpass on Android is/has a browser)
10. Good/thorough support.  Forums, how-tos, what have you.  If paid software, then timely support with a noncumbersome UI (chat, email, etc).
11. Not too much of a headache if the account is not a web page account.

**Nice to haves**

1. Easy enough to use for me to recommend to nontechnical users
2. iOS support
3. Open Source
4. Free as in $0
5. Support for [Tor browser bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en), [PaleMoon](http://www.palemoon.org/)
6. Works/compatible with [Seafile](http://seafile.com/)

Comment: While waiting for good recommendations: From your thorough description (+1 for that) I assume you've already checked with our other [Windows Password-Manager questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password-manager+windows)?

Comment: Before someone puts time/effort into it... have you tried Keepass with KeeFox plug-in?

Comment: Last I looked into KeePass, you had to really hack some stuff together to get synchronization across devices. I wanna say that was 4 years ago? DropBox was relatively new on the scene...

Comment: I use keepass on my PC with keefox linking to Firefox, and sync the key file through dropbox to my android phone. Granted, I rarely use it on android - typically only when I'm borrowing a PC and can't remember a password. But once I got it set up, it was pretty seamless. What do you need to do with it on Android?

Comment: Log in to things. Thought that was obvious. Lasypass has a feature that will do in app logins, which would be great if it would work. Their keyboard thing is pretty snazzy too.

Comment: So you need both browser and app integration on Android? Any specific browser?

Comment: Keepass has a database file you can sync however you like. I use syncthing. You use seafile. Keepass also has auto-typing.

Comment: @DanWhaley https://www.dashlane.com/

Answer (score 6):

[KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/) is the one I recommend and meets your requirements for desktop. However it does [recommend other good apps for mobile](https://keepassxc.org/docs/#faq-platform-mobile).

Edit: This answer formerly recommended [Keepass](https://keepass.info). KeepassXC is an open source community fork of Keepass with compatibility & development improvements.

Comment: According to their [FAQ](https://keepassxc.org/docs/#faq-platform-mobile), there isn't an Android or any other mobile-app version. Did you have a different idea in mind for meeting this requirement from the OP?

Comment: I use the one recommended in the FAQ question you linked.

Comment: It would be best to update your answer to note your recommendation doesn't meet the OP's requirement on that point, but that some other apps (e.g. the one recommended by their FAQ) can fill in the gap.

Answer (score 0):

[Bitwarden](https://bitwarden.com/) is what I upgraded to after leaving Lastpass.

Comment: Please add a reason why this would be better; specifically if it meets (all) the requirements of the question. Right now this is just [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)